# JSON_CONTAINS not returning result when used in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, json, mariadb, prepared-statement

I am writing a subquery to show certain information from a journal if a character is shown. Here is my function.

```
function getcharacterstories($con, $characterid) {
    
    $id = '"'.$characterid.'"';
    
    $sql = "SELECT dtr_entries.entreetitle,
                   dtr_entries.entreeinternallink, 
                   dtr_entries.entreetimestamp
            FROM dtr_entries 
            WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(entreeattachments, ?, '$.character')
            AND dtr_entries.entreetype = 3";
    
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    
    if(!$con->connect_errno) {
                
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

        if ($stmt) {

            if (!empty($characterid)) {
                
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i' , $id);
                
            }
        
            // shoot it all to the database

            if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    
                echo "error in following query:". $sql; 
                                    
                echo 'stmt error: '.mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);

            } else {
                
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $title, $link, $timestamp);

                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        
                    echo $title;
        
                }
                
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                
            }   
            
        } else {
            
            pre($con);
            
            echo $sql; 
                    
            die('mysqli error: '.mysqli_error($con));
            
        }
        
    } else {
        
        die( 'connect error: '.mysqli_connect_error() );
        
    }
    
}
```

The code on itself is correct, but returns empty (no errors what so ever). When i run this with numbers in the sql panel of phpmyadmin and i use double quotes arround my value in json contains, i actually get result, hence i reformatted the `characterid` to the `id`, but still no result.

The query in phpmyadmin that yields result is as following.

```
SELECT dtr_entries.entreetitle, dtr_entries.entreeinternallink, dtr_entries.entreetimestamp FROM dtr_entries WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(entreeattachments, '"1"', '$.character') AND dtr_entries.entreetype = 3
```

The data that is stored in the column entreeattachements is as following

```
{"character":"1","updated-by":"Lazarus","update-time":1599124101}
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix this?

This is btw the 10.2.27 MariaDB.

Comment: 1. Turn `error_reporting` on/up when you're developing new code so that you can actually see the error mesages. 2. The error message would probably indicate that you need to escape that `$` since it's in a double-quoted string.

Comment: @Sammitch error reporting is on. in all my files i got the ini commands turned on for logging,  And if the statement sql query would contain an error, i would have gotten a result back in the form of an error. hence all the checks. Further more, the error logs are empty.

Comment: which database you are using Mysql or MariaDB ?

Comment: @VishalSheth 10.2.27 MariaDB. See main information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

Originally `$characterid` may have been an integer, but you would have changed this here:

```
$id = '"'.$characterid.'"';
```

and as a result may not successfully bind as an integer here:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i' , $id);
```

### Possible Solutions

#### Approach 1

You could consider ensuring binding as a string as shown below

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's' , $id);
```

It would be best to ensure `$characterid` is indeed an integer eg.

```
$id = '"'.intval($characterid).'"';
```

#### Approach 2

or  updating your sql to quote the parameter as intended:

```
$sql = "SELECT dtr_entries.entreetitle,
                   dtr_entries.entreeinternallink, 
                   dtr_entries.entreetimestamp
            FROM dtr_entries 
            WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(entreeattachments, '\"?\"', '$.character')
            AND dtr_entries.entreetype = 3";
```

and using

```
$id = $characterid;
```

### Additional Resources

Determining if there was an error during the bind -https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: i will walk by this solution later on today when i have access to the pc i got my code on.

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in ....  Binding parameters failed: (0)` I added a fail save on the binding too and you are right, however both items fail, either wen i try both approaches.

Comment: It was a quote thing in the query that threw it off, i went for solution number one, but i modified it a tat, but you put me in the right direction, credits due!